# dropdown filter in user reference field

Tags: views, entities

I made a content type and then added a user reference field to it. Name of this field is "expert_users" that references to 500 users. I should use check boxes widget type for it. Now, when I add/edit a node, all of 500 users are loaded in the "expert_users" field. I thought to insert a dropdown list exposed filter on users' roles to reduce the number of the users referenced. So, instead of display 500 users on content, only 20 users with the selected role (of drop-down list) would be displayed. I don't know how to add this drop-down list.

I am trying to use the Views module to select the users (Advanced option) in the CCK field, but it only shows field names, not exposed filters of the user reference view.

Do you have any idea? Do I have to work with `hook_form_alter()`?

I am using Drupal6.22, and CCK-6.x-2.x-dev.